# Nested queries in check SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a constraint (in Oracle), that restricts the user from creating an entries having 'smth', 'smth else' or 'one more thing' in a field already exist. Basically, that's how I would write it:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable
ADD CONSTRAINT sometable_text_chk
CHECK (
    caption IN ( 
        SELECT caption
        FROM sometable
        WHERE text NOT IN ('smth', 'smth else', 'one more thing')
    )
)
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be not allowed to nest queries for this occasion. Is there perhaps a workaround.

Comment: This is not so clear - what is the relation between fields `text` and `caption`? what do you mean when you say 'restricts the user from creating an entries ... in a field already exist'? (are you talking about wanting to have unique values in field `caption`???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are trying to have some sort of a general check on the validity of the data in one table based on the data in another table (NOTE: actually probably not, waiting for the OP to clarify his question).

Workaround is either:

- for general case - you can do quite a lot inside triggers in terms of complex data validation (including bringing your database to a halt for even the simplest of update queries, so use with care)
- for a bit more specific case, you are trying to accomplish some dynamic validation (a more representative example would have been useful) - you can dynamically maintain the CHECK constraint with a 'snapshot' of your validation (this boils down to keeping a copy of the referenced table inside the check statement, so it is quite ugly)
- maybe you can make a foreign key check. this is not how you normally design databases, but if you look at it semantically - you claim (with your CHECK) that there is a relationship between this table and some other entity. well, if that entity is not realised as separate table, maybe it should have been? (these kinds of problems are *sometimes* indicators of bad design)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE sometable 
ADD CONSTRAINT sometable_text_chk 
CHECK (text not in ('smth', 'smth else', 'one more thing'))
/
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but the requirement is a bit more complex... you need to find the value in a lookup table, not the key itself

Comment: But alex specifically mentioned "sometable" twice. And without a schema specified, that can only be the same table. You might be right though, but then I'm impressed at how you can read between the lines :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add such CHECK constraint, you need literally provide whole list of possible values:

```
CHECK (caption IN (Word1, Word2, Word3 ...))
```

However you can do in other way:

```
CHECK (Caption <> 'smth' and caption <> 'smth else' and caption <> 'one more thing')
```

But you lost checks from sometable.

Answer (score 0):

I admit this may be overkill. If you can create a fast-refreshable, refresh-on-commit materialized view with a definition that would count the number of bad values in your table, (maybe something like below):

```
select count(*) as rows_with_errors
  from data_table   a
  join lookup_table b on(a.caption = b.caption);
```

The query should return a count of zero, because values in data_table may NOT contain the values in the lookup_table. Then you create a check constraint on the materialized view itself, CHECK(rows_with_errors = 0).

Whenever an update or insert is committed into data_table, the materialized view will refresh. But (and here is the thing), if you entered a value in data_table that exists in lookup_table, the count(*) will return a non-zero value, which will cause the check constraint on the materialized view to fail, thus the entire insert/update statement will fail/rollback. Voila!